# Group individual level data into grouped level list and search for presence %in% that list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

in R I have a twofold problem.

First,

I would like to transform my data from this:

```
d <- data.table(
  person_id=1:10,
  cat=letters[1:10],
  group_id=c(rep(1,5),rep(2,5))
)
```

Into this:

```
d_grouped <- data.table(
  group_id=1:2
)
d_grouped$Cat_grouped <- list(letters[1:5],letters[6:10] )
```

i.e. group my data, from person level to group level, but keeping the information on individual characteristics into a column containing list of person level characteristics for each group.

How can I do this aggregation?

Preferably a data.table solution. But it could also be a normal data.frame.

Second,

I would like to search for presence of the elements of a vector in each list of each group

Something like (I know this is not correct syntax):

```
c('a','b') %in% d_grouped$Cat_grouped
```

which should return another list:

```
list(c(T,T),c(F,F))
```

More broadly, I am trying to merge lists (A and B) both containing vectors. The match should be based on the elements of a vector in list A being present on a vector in list B. Is there any merge command based on this SubVector logic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To accomplish the first transformation,

```
d[, list(Cat_grouped=paste0(cat, collapse = ',')), group_id]
```

To accomplish the second, it seems as though your best bet is to leave the data in the original shape?  After all

```
d[, c('a', 'b') %in% cat, group_id]
```

returns

```
  group_id    V1
1:        1  TRUE
2:        1  TRUE
3:        2 FALSE
4:        2 FALSE
```

All this being said your "more broadly" appears to be asking for something else which I fear is not quite what I've helped you with by answering the two specific questions.  Perhaps you could provide another example?

Comment: I think you are right about just doing this analysis in the current shape. I'm not sure there is necessarily any advantage to splitting into separate lists.

Comment: @HarlandMason: tks for great answers. I described the broader issue in this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45406977/merge-lists-of-vectors-based-on-one-vector-bellonging-to-another-vector . I would apreciate if you could take a look

Answer (score 2):

Just do it in `data.table`, returning a list for each `by=` group:

```
d[, .(cat_grouped=.(cat)), by=group_id]
#   group_id cat_grouped
#1:        1   a,b,c,d,e
#2:        2   f,g,h,i,j
```

I tend to agree with @HarlandMason's answer that the analysis you are doing does not however require this intermediate data.table.

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution using `aggregate`

```
d2 = aggregate(list(cat = d$cat), list(group = d$group_id), function(x)
                                        as.character(x), simplify = FALSE)
d2
#  group           cat
#1     1 a, b, c, d, e
#2     2 f, g, h, i, j

lapply(d2$cat, function(x) c("a","b") %in% x)
#$`1`
#[1] TRUE TRUE

#$`2`
#[1] FALSE FALSE
```

Also consider

```
mylist = split(d$cat, d$group_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
d %>%
    group_by(group_id) %>% 
    summarise(cat = list(cat))
```