# How to merge lists of vectors based on one vector belonging to another vector?

Tags: r, list, merge, data.table

In R, I have two data frames that contain list columns

```
d1 <- data.table(
  group_id1=1:4
)
d1$Cat_grouped <- list(letters[1:2],letters[3:2],letters[3:6],letters[11:12] )
```

And

```
d_grouped <- data.table(
  group_id2=1:4
)
d_grouped$Cat_grouped <- list(letters[1:5],letters[6:10],letters[1:2],letters[1] )
```

I would like to merge these two data.tables based on the vectors in `d1$Cat_grouped` being contained in the vectors in `d_grouped$Cat_grouped`

To be more precise, there could be two matching criteria:

a) all elements of each vector of `d1$Cat_grouped` must be in the matched vector of `d_grouped$Cat_grouped`

Resulting in the following match:

```
result_a <- data.table(
   group_id1=c(1,2)
   group_id2=c(1,1)
)
```

b) at least one of the elements in each vector of `d1$Cat_grouped` must be in the matched vector of `d_grouped$Cat_grouped`

Resulting in the following match:

```
result_b <- data.table(
  group_id1=c(1,2,3,3),
  group_id2=c(1,1,1,2)
)
```

How can I implement a) or b) ? Preferably in a data.table way.

EDIT1: added the expected results of a) and b)

EDIT2: added more groups to d_grouped, so grouping variables overlap. This breaks some of the proposed solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer focuses on part *a)* of the question.

It follows [Harland's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45407137/3817004) but tries to make better use of the `data.table` idiom for performance reasons as the OP has mentioned that his production data may contain millions of observations.

#### Sample data

```
library(data.table)
d1 <- data.table(
  group_id1 = 1:4,
  Cat_grouped = list(letters[1:2], letters[3:2], letters[3:6], letters[11:12]))

d_grouped <- data.table(
  group_id2 = 1:2,
  Cat_grouped = list(letters[1:5], letters[6:10]))
```

#### Result a)

```
grp_cols <- c("group_id1", "group_id2")
unique(d1[, .(unlist(Cat_grouped), lengths(Cat_grouped)), by = group_id1][
  d_grouped[, unlist(Cat_grouped), by = group_id2], on = "V1", nomatch = 0L][
    , .(V2, .N), by = grp_cols][V2 == N, ..grp_cols])

   group_id1 group_id2
1:         1         1
2:         2         1
```

#### Explanation

While expanding the list elements of `d1` and `d_grouped` into long format, the number of list elements is determined for `d1` using the `lengths()` function. `lengths()` (note the difference to `length()`) gets the length of each element of a list and was introduced with R 3.2.0.

After the inner join (note the `nomatch = 0L` parameter), the number of rows in the result set is counted (using the specal symbol `.N`) for each combination of `grp_cols`. Only those rows are considered where the count in the result set does match the original length of the list. Finally, the unique combinations of `grp_cols` are returned.

#### Result b)

Result b) can be derived from above solution by omitting the counting stuff:

```
unique(d1[, unlist(Cat_grouped), by = group_id1][
  d_grouped[, unlist(Cat_grouped), by = group_id2], on = "V1", nomatch = 0L][
      , c("group_id1", "group_id2")])
```

> ```
>    group_id1 group_id2
> 1:         1         1
> 2:         2         1
> 3:         3         1
> 4:         3         2
> ```

Answer (score 4):

So I think long form is better, though my answer feels a little roundabout.  I bet someone whose a little sleeker with data table can do this in fewer steps, but here's what I've got:

first, let's unpack the vectors in your example data:

```
d1_long <- d1[, list(cat=unlist(Cat_grouped)), group_id1]
d_grouped_long <- d_grouped[, list(cat=unlist(Cat_grouped)), group_id2]
```

Now, we can merge on the individual elements:

```
result_b <- merge(d1_long, d_grouped_long, by='cat')
```

Based on our example, it seems you don't actually need to know which elements were part of the match...

```
result_b[, cat := NULL]
```

Finally, my answer has duplicated group_id pairs because it gets a join for each pairwise match, not just the vector-level matches.  So we can unique them away.

```
result_b <- unique(result_b)
```

Here's my result_b:

```
   group_id.1 group_id.2
1:          1          1
2:          2          1
3:          3          1
4:          3          2
```

We can use b as an intermediate step to a, since having any elements in common is a subset of having all elements in common.

Let's merge the original tables to see what the candidates are in terms of subvectors and vectors

```
result_a <- merge(result_b, d1, by = 'group_id1')
result_a <- merge(result_a, d_grouped, by = 'group_id2')
```

So now, if the length of Cat_grouped.x matches the number of TRUEs about Cat_grouped.x being %in% Cat_grouped.y, that's a bingo.

I tried a handful of clean ways, but the weirdness of having lists in the data table defeated the most obvious attempts.  This seems to work though:

Let's add a `row` column to operate `by`

```
result_a[, row := 1:.N]
```

Now let's get the length and number of matches...

```
result_a[, x.length := length(Cat_grouped.x[[1]]), row]
result_a[, matches := sum(Cat_grouped.x[[1]] %in% Cat_grouped.y[[1]]), row]
```

And filter down to just rows where length and matches are the same

```
result_a <- result_a[x.length==matches]
```

Comment: great. Tks. You provided the result for question b) (I had misplaced the expected output). Would you dare tackle question a) ?

Comment: haha, I stopped short because you said "or" in your question so I thought perhaps this was sufficient. I've been playing with it and seems harder, but I'll keep poking at it.

Comment: For a) , I guess you could do the merge in a left-join way, so all the elements of d1_long would be preserved, even the unmatched ones. Then count the number of distinct elements of group_id.y per group_id.x. Then keep only if this count ==1 and there are no NAs in group_id.y

Comment: I've edited this answer to include my crack at a).  Though what your describing sounds like it might requirer fewer intermediate steps and so is probably better!

Comment: Your code doesn't work with the data as provided by the OP: *object 'group_id' not found*

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing this out.  I think his question got edited underneath me.  I'll fix my answer

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

Cross-join to get all pairs of group ids:

```
Y = CJ(group_id1=d1$group_id1, group_id2=d_grouped$group_id2)
```

Then merge in the vectors:

```
Y = Y[d1, on='group_id1'][d_grouped, on='group_id2']

#    group_id1 group_id2 Cat_grouped i.Cat_grouped
# 1:         1         1         a,b     a,b,c,d,e
# 2:         2         1         c,b     a,b,c,d,e
# 3:         3         1     c,d,e,f     a,b,c,d,e
# 4:         4         1         k,l     a,b,c,d,e
# 5:         1         2         a,b     f,g,h,i,j
# 6:         2         2         c,b     f,g,h,i,j
# 7:         3         2     c,d,e,f     f,g,h,i,j
# 8:         4         2         k,l     f,g,h,i,j
```

Now you can use `mapply` to filter however you like:

```
Y[mapply(function(u,v) all(u %in% v), Cat_grouped, i.Cat_grouped), 1:2]
#    group_id1 group_id2
# 1:         1         1
# 2:         2         1

Y[mapply(function(u,v) length(intersect(u,v)) > 0, Cat_grouped, i.Cat_grouped), 1:2]
#    group_id1 group_id2
# 1:         1         1
# 2:         2         1
# 3:         3         1
# 4:         3         2
```

Comment: This is nice and elegant. But in my use case, d1 and d_grouped can have millions of observations. So just creating cross-join physically will be too expensive in terms of memory use.